# Send a 60Hz trig signal over a 9m cable

Tags: 3.3v, 24v, long-distance, signal-conversion

I want to send a trig signal over a 9m cable, the signal is around 60Hz (each 15ms it sends a 1ms pulse). In order to avoid electrical interference I convert the 3.3V original signal with the following circuit:

[image]

I have a power supply of 24V available so this circuit is converting the 0 to 3.3V signal into 0 to 22V, my questions is: is it ok to send 1ms pulses using 24V or should I use a lower power supply of 12V? On the other side I have an opto-coupler and a current limiter of 10mA.

Comment: 15 ms is 66.67 Hz and not 60 Hz.

Comment: Shoud be no issue. Do you have any strong radio transmitters nearby?

Comment: @winny No RF transmission in the vicinity, probably WiFi hubs in the same room thats all.

Comment: No issues. Report your findings once built!